# ESP-32 Не выходит из цикла

Tags: c++, esp32, arduino-ide

Всех приветствую.
Не пойму в чём проблема.
ESP-32 не хочет выходить из цикла.
Пишу на ArduinoIDE.
Пробовал и `break` и `continue` и `while` вместо `for`, ничего не помогает.
Пока не выполнит цикл, ничего нельзя сделать.
На ESP-8266 то же самое. Думал дело в плате.

```cpp
if ((mcp4.digitalRead(button1) == LOW || wb == 1) && fn == 2) {
    priceFunc = price1;
    btnName = btn1;
    Serial.println(btnName);
    Serial.println(price1);
    Serial.println("str 1477 " + cash);
    Serial.println("///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////");
    fn = 1;
    h = 1;
    fds1;

    for(int i; i = timePause; i++){
      if (millis() - Timer > 1000) {
        Timer = millis();
        timePause--;
        Serial.print("Time Pause ");
        Serial.println(timePause);
      }
      if( wb == 2 || wb == 3 || fn == 2 || fn == 3){
        break;
      }
    }      
  }
```

Comment: `i == timePause`

Comment: @ГерманБорисов даже так есть вероятность, что условие на равенство не выполнится. Я бы на < поменял.

Comment: Сейчас попробую

Comment: За счет чего в этом цикле может случится выход? `wb` `fn`  не изменяются, `i = timePause` присваивание

Comment: У вас в самом заголовке цикла какая-то ерунда написана. Зачем вы инкременируете `i`, если всё равно перезаписываете его через `timePause`? Если `timePause` гарантированно больше нуля, то декркментируйте его просто `for (timePause = 10; timePause; --timePause)`

Comment: Для справки, значением выражения `lv = rv` будет `lv`, т.е. `while (lv = rv)` - валидно, хотя компилятор может ругаться, если не обернуть в дополнительные скобки `while ((lv = rv))`.

Comment: == и < не помогли

Comment: Так-же timePause вместо i в for тоже не помогло